# How to render image return from the API with the ContentType image/jpeg

Tags: angularjs, api, content-type

I have an external API that return back image in response, the ContentType: image/jpeg.. I am using angular to make call to the services. How can I bind the image on the view through my view model

```
 var deffered = $q.defer();
            resource.get(paramters, function (data) {
                deffered.resolve(data);
            }, function (status) {
                deffered.reject(status);
      });
return deffered.promise;

datacontext.getImage()
       .then(function (data) {
       //what to do with data?
        });
```

Comment: You can directly embedd the webapi url in the img src property.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible. I have a collection of records and with each individual there is an image associated with it. I can not directly embedd the web api url in the image src.

Comment: You can embed an expression that returns the webapi url, where the image is located, assuming you yourself are making get request in your  code. Something like `<img ng-src='buildUrl()'`. `buildUrl` can map to the api endpoint that is sending image.

Comment: Glad it helped! Adding it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comments as answer

You can embed an expression that returns the webapi url, where the image is located, assuming you yourself are making `GET` request in your code. Something like `<img ng-src='buildUrl()'`. `buildUrl` can map to the api endpoint that is sending image.